# Theme crocal - link menu problem : still redirect to homepage

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, menu, themes

I try to search a solution but I have no answer. My links menu don't work at all. When I click on it, they redirect always to the homepage. Only when I'm logged as admin they works.

I tried to deactivate all my plugins, recreate a menu from scratch, another from the administration and change the permalinks but the problem still in. I took a look on .htaccess but it's the basic one, so it's not this.

Here the website : [primmoconseil.fr](https://primmoconseil.fr) .

Please help me for this :)

Comment: If you show what you have tried, you might get more answers. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try to change permalink http://prntscr.com/r3z26x

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you are not pointing menus to the right pages. When creating a menu, it is important you select the page you want it to point to.

Be sure to have added pages first. and when creating menus, be sure they are each pointing to the page you want to load.

this might help

https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-add-navigation-menu-in-wordpress-beginners-guide/

If it does not, let me know so we figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers! :)

To answer you mw509, I know how to create a WordPress Menu and I've already tried to recreate one and another from scratch.
I just found few minutes ago, it's because of my theme used. When I changed, it's work. But I have no choice to use this theme (my client want this one absolutely). 
So how can I do...?

Here my permalinks configuration :https://primmoconseil.fr/%postname%/%post_id%/.

And here my htaccess page :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you again to help me :)